# How can I output the product name, the color and its color quantity that is less than 10 as a list?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

[![This is the following data from the Firebase. Take note that some of the products have 1, 2 or 3 colours in each products. I want the color and the color quantity that is less than 10 to output ][1]][1]

[![his is the output of the code. This is what I want it to look like. But in the output as you can see the colour is too close to the quantity and that the product Tumbler it outputted a colour that is not less than 10.][2]][2]

> This is the code that I'm having trouble with.

```
    <ul>
    {details.filter((detail) => Object.values(detail.colorMap).find(c => c < 10)).map((val) => 
    {
    return (<li key={val.id}><p className="pt-2">{val.prodName}{Object.entries(val.colorMap).map((c) => (<p>{c[0]}{c[1]}</p>))}</p></li>);
    })}
    </ul>
```

Comment: Can you share screenshot of current output in list and expected output? The code does filter out items where any color is less than 10

Comment: Yes, it outputted the products with less than 10 color quantity. But as you can see in the screenshot above the Tumbler one it also outputted the color Red which is not less than 10, it should only output Blue and pink. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: The code currently shows items where at least any one color is less than 10. Like you want to show Tumbler but only Blue and Pink in colors?

Comment: Yes, like that. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another `filter()` to get colours with value less than 10 only as shown below:

```
<p className="pt-2">
  {val.prodName}
  {Object.entries(val.colorMap)
    // Filter for colors with value < 10
    .filter((c) => c[1] < 10)
    .map((c) => (
      <p>
        {c[0]}
        {c[1]}
      </p>
    ))}
</p>
```

Comment: @ImranNoir yes, this will be inside of `<li key={val.id}> HERE </li>`

Comment: It worked man! Thanks bro. But one last request the colorname is too close to the number of quantity. Can it space out a little?

Comment: @ImranNoir depends on how you want in the UI. Maybe try adding some margin top to color list elements  `<p className="mt-1">`

Comment: It didn't work bro

Comment: Are you using any CSS framework or so? If yes, you can check what classes they use to add margin and you can just use that class to add some spacing.